# Fail stage on failed expressions in Spinnaker pipeline stag

Tags: devops, pipeline, spinnaker

I am working on Spinnaker Pipeline. I noticed there is an option called `Fail stage on failed expressions` when editing the stag through the Web UI. I didn't find any explanation about it in the docs, could somebody give an example about it?

Answer (score 0):

This option is used to fail stage if any pipeline expression like `${}` inside it failed to be processed even if stage itself was successful.

For example for `Evaluate Variables` stage this option is enabled by default.